# How to get name of current package in go?

Tags: go

Is there a way to get on runtime the name of current package?

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    pkgName := {some magic here:)}
    fmt.Println(pkgName)
}
```

... and the result should be "main"

Right now I'm using constant like:

```
package main

import "fmt"
const (
    pkgName = "main"
)

func main() {
    fmt.Println(pkgName)
}
```

but I'm curious if you can avoid this

Answer (score 41, accepted):

There is no [runtime](http://golang.org/pkg/runtime/) or [reflect](http://golang.org/pkg/reflect/) method or function that provides the functionality that you are looking for.

The closest thing I could find is:

```
package main

import (
    "azul3d.org/lmath.v1"
    "fmt"
    "reflect"
)

type Empty struct{}

func main() {
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(Empty{}).PkgPath())
    fmt.Println(reflect.TypeOf(lmath.Vec3{0, 0, 0}).PkgPath())
}
```

This would output:

```
main
azul3d.org/lmath.v1
```

You could also read the first line of the file and remove the "package" substring.
(Not sure if it's the best idea)

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "bytes"
    "fmt"
    "os"
)

func main() {
    file, err := os.Open("so.go")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    r := bufio.NewReader(file)
    line, _, err := r.ReadLine()
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    packageName := bytes.TrimPrefix(line, []byte("package "))
    fmt.Println(string(packageName))
}
```

Comment: Even an answer that there is no nice way to do that is a good answer so I'm already upvoting it (especially it provides good ideas), but I will wait a bit before accepting it, just to give a chance to others.

Comment: Reading the "first line" is not sufficient, as there are often comments (including build directives) before the 'package' line.

Comment: I'm downvoting simply because the other answer has shown a method for accomplishing this with the `runtime` package, where at the start of your answer you state "...no runtime or reflect method or function...".

Comment: downvoting for the same reason as Seer, and themue's solution works perfectly

Comment: This solution is way more succinct. It’s really a language mistake to not easily be able to fully qualify all symbols in the same file. This always becomes a need at scale

Answer (score 32):

Here a part of my logger package. It retrieves information about the caller of the logging function to show it later in the output.

```
func retrieveCallInfo() *callInfo {
    pc, file, line, _ := runtime.Caller(2)
    _, fileName := path.Split(file)
    parts := strings.Split(runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name(), ".")
    pl := len(parts)
    packageName := ""
    funcName := parts[pl-1]

    if parts[pl-2][0] == '(' {
        funcName = parts[pl-2] + "." + funcName
        packageName = strings.Join(parts[0:pl-2], ".")
    } else {
        packageName = strings.Join(parts[0:pl-1], ".")
    }

    return &callInfo{
        packageName: packageName,
        fileName:    fileName,
        funcName:    funcName,
        line:        line,
    }
}
```

As you can see it returns the package name too.

Comment: What logger package are you using this in? Is it an OSS project?

Comment: Also, it looks like packageName is more than just the package name, it's the package name and the method?

Comment: actualy, it's not package name, it's file name

Comment: I would first split `runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name()` on the last "/" to get the prefix for the path for the packagename and packagename.funcname...

Then will continue to split the packagename.funcname.. on the `.` character to get the packagename followed by the top level func name.

Answer (score 6):

To reliably get the package name, you can use the go compiler's parser to parse only the package clause.

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "go/ast"
    "go/parser"
    "go/token"
)

func packageName(file string) (string, error) {
    fset := token.NewFileSet()

    // parse the go soure file, but only the package clause
    astFile, err := parser.ParseFile(fset, l.path, nil, parser.PackageClauseOnly)
    if err != nil {
        return "", err
    }

    if astFile.Name == nil {
        return "", fmt.Errorf("no package name found")
    }

    return astFile.Name.Name, nil
}
```

Comment: Where does `l.path` come from? It doesn't exist!

Comment: this assumes the source of the program is available to itself. What happens if you copy just the binary to a different machine?

Answer (score 2):

## Better Solution

I actually found a better solution, in this function down here you just simply pass a function and the output is gonna be simple and straight.

```golang
package main

import (
    "reflect"
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

func GetPackageName(temp interface{}) string {
    strs := strings.Split((runtime.FuncForPC(reflect.ValueOf(temp).Pointer()).Name()), ".")
    strs = strings.Split(strs[len(strs)-2], "/")
    return strs[len(strs)-1]
}
```

And this is an example of how you use this:

```golang
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(GetPackageName(main))
}
```

And this is the answer you should expect:

```sh
main
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a very low tech solution from an application of mine, this will return the package a variable is from:

```golang
func pkgName(x interface{}) string {
    varType := strings.TrimPrefix(fmt.Sprintf("%T", x), "*")
    return strings.TrimSuffix(varType, path.Ext(varType))
}
```

To get the current package declare a variable locally and pass it in.

Answer (score -1):

This might help:

```
import (
    "runtime"
    "strings"
)

func Package() string {
    pc, _, _, _ := runtime.Caller(1)
    parts := strings.Split(runtime.FuncForPC(pc).Name(), ".")
    pl := len(parts)
    pkage := ""
    funcName := parts[pl-1]
    if parts[pl-2][0] == '(' {
        funcName = parts[pl-2] + "." + funcName
        pkage = strings.Join(parts[0:pl-2], ".")
    } else {
        pkage = strings.Join(parts[0:pl-1], ".")
    }
    return pkage
}
```

Comment: Could you add an explanation for your code? Especially since there are already many other answers that look very similar to yours, it would help your answer a lot if you let readers now how it is different and/or better.